# plot mp3 file as waveform in Java

Tags: java, plot, mp3, waveform

I want to plot the waveform of an mp3 file (like we see in various media players). I guess the amplitude is plotted against time. I want to do this using Java.
I have Googled a lot about this but did not come up with a proper solution. However, I came across something called "PCM" and "FTT" (about which I have no idea and seemingly too complex).
I did get some help on another post on plotting a wav file. However, I cannot plot an mp3 file.
Could you be kind enough to help me out (if possible with an actual code).

Thank you !

Comment: [PCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation) is the amplitude-vs-time waveform data that computer sound hardware understands, and it's the form that's suitable for plotting.  If you're starting from some other format, such as MP3 or Vorbis, you'll need to decode it into PCM first — both for playback and for plotting.

Comment: okk ... but how to decode it to PCM from mp3 and then how to plot that PCM ?? (irrespective of the bitrate of the mp3 file, etc)